# Drupal Mailchimp module for multilanguage sites

Tags: 7, emails

I setup a D7 multi-language site. People can subscribe with my MailChimp newsletter list when they register at **user/register**.

It works fine with **german**, the default language, but when somebody switches to **english**, registers at **/user/register** with the *Subscribe to our Newsletter* set, the double opt-in email the user receives from MailChimp is still **german**, not **english**.

How can I create MailChimp signup form that sticks with the current selected language?

Comment: Same problem here. I have two mailchimp lists (EN and PL). Default language is PL and even I've set-up different path for English after submitting I'm redirect always to default language. In my case PL.